# Matching ORB Features with a threshold

Tags: android, opencv, matching, threshold, orb

My project is herbs recognition based on android. I use ORB to get keypoints, features, and matching the features.

I want to use this algorithm:

1. I use 4 reference image, and matching their features image1 to image1, 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-3, 3,4.
2. Then I store the minimum and maximum distance to database as a threshold. (minimum threshold = total minimum/6)
3. When I recognize the new image, I compare that new minimum and maximum distance with in database. But I don't know how to do that.

{

```
for (j=MinID; j<=MaxID; j++){
                        MatOfDMatch matches = DetectUtility.match(features, matFromJson(DB.GetORBFitur(j)));
                        List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();
                        Double max_dist = 0.0;
                        Double min_dist = 100.0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < matchesList.size(); i++){
                            Double dist = (double) matchesList.get(i).distance;
                            if (dist < min_dist && dist != 0){
                                min_dist = dist;
                            }
                            if (dist > max_dist){
                                max_dist = dist;
                            }
                        }
```

From [this site](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html), I get this code:

```
//-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
{ if( matches[i].distance < 3*min_dist )
 { good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); }
}
```

How to get that magic number 3?
and what must I do to the maximum distance?

The algoritma that I want to use, I used before on using Invariant Moment, and City Block Distance to matching the image with the smallest distance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don`t know either. Distance is measure of the feature point similarity, less is better. The [original ORB paper](http://www.vision.cs.chubu.ac.jp/CV-R/pdf/Rublee_iccv2011.pdf) (fig. 5, below) shows distribution of the distances for good and bad matches. One can surely says that "good" distance threshold would be around 64.
[image: Distance distribution for ORB]

So more correct is :

```
double dist_th = 64;
for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
{ if( matches[i].distance < dist_th )
 { good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); }
}
```

And then you still have to use RANSAC to filter inconsistent matches. So, the simplest solution is to do match you query image with all 4 database images.

But I`d advise you to use some classifier, not just matching. See this guy approach (it works, I know him) - http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~sulcmila/

Comment: thanks for the answer :) but i still don't know how to match my new image with the image on database after have the good_matches. How can my new image considered match witch one on the database?

Comment: What do you mean by "match"? Do you mean "to consider this herb is one from db"? I think, you can if you have geometric verified matches from RANSAC, but this is very rare case to me. Consider shape and texture classification.