# What are the exact threshold for ORB Feature matching(and hamming distance)?

Tags: python, opencv, feature-detection, orb

I use ORB to get keypoints, features, and matching the features with python.
My project is an AR program with ORB. So I want to know whether or not the marker exists in front of the camera.

I am not sure what the threshold is.

For example, I compared those 2 images.

[Images to be compared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALN9w.jpg)

They are definitely different images. Top 15 Hamming Distance Values are : [41.0, 41.0, 43.0, 44.0, 46.0, 46.0, 48.0, 48.0, 48.0, 48.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 50.0]

I already read this answer too.

[Matching ORB Features with a threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857398/matching-orb-features-with-a-threshold)

But my values are smaller than 64 even they are different features. Is there any thesis about ORB threshold? What is the correct threshold? Or, are the thresholds different for each image?

Comment: depends on your task, your image quality, noise, and so on...

Comment: Even I am working on a project using ORB for AR. I have observed that Hamming distance is one way to analyze the descriptors. I have used KNN matching. I agree with @Micka , you can tweak the threshold, there's no specific number.